# Email not send to buyer in paypal using sandox ipn

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

Hi there i am working on a paypal plugin that add a responder, add products.

I am working on a sandbox for testing.

I make responder than add products related responder. On front end when i click on the "Buy" button, it goes to sandbox.paypal and here i complete the procedure of payment and on my dummy merchant account i accept the payment and know the email send to buyer of completion but the email not send i read the code 10 times but i dont get the issue.

Here is my code:

Paypal form:

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="'.$paypalID.'">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="'.$return_url.'">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="'.$currency.'">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="'.$product_name.'">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" id="p'.$product_id.'" value="'.$product_price.'">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="'.$responderID.'">
    <input name="notify_url" value="'.plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'ipn_sandbox.php" type="hidden">
    <input type="image" src="'.$upload_image.'" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - its fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

And here is my ipn_sandbox.php code:

```
<?php
    // STEP 1: Read POST data
    // reading posted data from directly from $_POST causes serialization 
    // issues with array data in POST
    // reading raw POST data from input stream instead. 

    $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);

    $myPost = array();
    foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
        $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);

        if (count($keyval) == 2)
            $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
    }

    // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
        $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
    } 

    foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {        
        if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) { 
            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
        } else {
            $value = urlencode($value);
        }
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }

    // STEP 2: Post IPN data back to paypal to validate
    $ch = curl_init('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

    if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
        curl_close($ch);
        exit; 
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

    include_once $path . '/wp-config.php';
    include_once $path . '/wp-load.php';
    include_once $path . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php';
    include_once $path . '/wp-includes/pluggable.php';

    global $wpdb;
    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
        $item_name              =   $_POST['item_name'];
        $item_number            =   $_POST['item_number'];
        $payment_status         =   $_POST['payment_status'];
        $payment_amount         =   $_POST['mc_gross'];
        $payment_currency       =   $_POST['mc_currency'];
        $txn_id                 =   $_POST['txn_id'];
        $receiver_email         =   $_POST['receiver_email'];
        $payer_email            =   $_POST['payer_email'];
        $responderID            =   $_POST['custom'];
        $name                   =   $_POST['first_name'];
        $payment_status         =   $_POST['payment_status'];
        $site_url               =   get_bloginfo('wpurl');
        $table_resp             =   $wpdb->prefix.'paypal_responders';
        $responder_to_use       =   $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $table_resp WHERE id ='$responderID'");
        $subject                =   $responder_to_use->subject;
        $from                   =   $responder_to_use->from_email;
        $attachment             =   $responder_to_use->attachment;
        $att_secure             =   $responder_to_use->att_secure;
        $message        .=  $responder_to_use->message_body;
        $message                .=  '<br /><br />
                                    <a title="Click here to download Attachment" href="'.plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'responders/download.php?filename='.$att_secure.'" width="150" height="150" target="_blank">Click here to download Attachment</a>';

        if($message){
            $message    =   str_replace('[item_name]',$item_name,$message);
            $message    =   str_replace('[txn_id]',$txn_id,$message);
            $message    =   str_replace(' [mc_gross]',$payment_amount,$message);
            $message    =   str_replace('[mc_currency]',$payment_currency,$message);
            $message    =   str_replace('[receiver_email]',$receiver_email,$message);
            $message    =   str_replace('[payer_email]',$payer_email,$message);
            $message    =   str_replace('[name]',$name,$message);
            $message    =   str_replace('[site_url]',$site_url,$message);
            $message    =   str_replace('[payment_status]',$payment_status,$message);
        }else{
            $message    =       'Dear '.$name.',
                                Thank you for your purchase from '.$site_url.'. The details of your purchase are below.
                                Transaction ID: '.$txn_id.'
                                Item Name: '.$item_name.'
                                Payment Amount: '.$payment_amount.'
                                Payment Amount: '.$payment_status.'
                                Paid to: '.$receiver_email.'
                                Thanks and Enjoy!
                                ~Enigma Digital <br />
                                <br />
                                <a title="Click here to download Attachment" href="'.plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'responders/download.php?filename='.$att_secure.'" width="150" height="150" target="_blank">Click here to download Attachment</a>';
        }

        $table          =   $wpdb->prefix . "paypal_transactions";
        $txn_id_check   =   $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE txn_id ='$txn_id'");

        if(!$txn_id_check){
            $data   =   array(
                            'txn_id'            =>      $txn_id,
                            'product_name'      =>      $item_name,
                            'product_price'     =>      $payment_amount,
                            'payer_email'       =>      $payer_email,
                        );

            $wpdb->insert($table,$data) or die(mysql_error());
            $num = md5(time());

            $headers .= 'From: ' .$from. "\r\n" .'Reply-To: ' .$from . "\r\n";
            $headers  .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers  .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 ";
            $headers  .= "--".$num."--";

            //mail to buyer
            mail( $payer_email , $subject, $message, $headers );
        }
    }
?>
```

I also use `wp_mail()` except `mail()` but nothing happen.

Please can anyone help what the issue is.

Comment: Are you testing on local machine or on an online server ? try `error_reporting` maybe it will help you debug the issue ..

Comment: @SyedQarib sahib i am using online server

Comment: Have you tried the error reporting ? Is there something you can find in the logs ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code, and a few things you can do to commence the debugging process.  It's unlikely you'll get a straightforward fix here though, as it's an open-ended question.

Before doing anything, please ensure `error_reporting` is set to `E^ALL` and `display_errors` is set to `On` in your `php.ini`.  ([Turorial, if you need it](http://php.about.com/od/troubleshooting/qt/php_error_reporting.htm)). Check your `error_log` - if one exists - for immediate clues.

You need to declare `$message` before appending more data to it.  You begin appending data to `$message`  on line 77 (`$message .=  $responder_to_use->message_body;`) but it hasn't been set yet, which will produce a Warning.

There are now 3 reasons why the email itself wouldn't be sent:

1. Your server isn't setup to send mail.
2. `$txn_id_check` isn't set or is `false`.  This would be the case if `$txn_id` is not in your database.  I'm assuming you add this row when beginning the transaction - but have you checked?
3. You have a syntax error in one of the included files.

---

Let's address #1.  Create a file on the server with 1 line that sends you a simple email:

```
<?php mail('your@email', 'Test email', 'Yay, I can send mail!'); ?>
```

Visit that file in your browser.  Check your inbox, and check your spam. No mail?  That's the issue.

---

Next #2:  This is likely a problem with the script that adds the transaction to the database before the user even gets to PayPal.  We don't have this code, but it's easy for you to check - just check the DB to see if you have any rows present.

---

And #3:  Syntax errors should be easy to check for here, just visit the IPN script directly in your browser.  Fatal errors will be displayed to you.

---

Still not working?  There may be issues elsewhere.  The best way to check is with some basic debugging...

Start by sending the full `$_POST` array to yourself over email, right at the top of the script.

```
<?php
    mail('your@email', 'Full Post Data - '.time(), print_r($_REQUEST, true));

    // STEP 1: Read POST data
    // reading posted data from directly from $_POST causes serialization 
    // issues with array data in POST
    // reading raw POST data from input stream instead. 

    $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);

    [...]
```

And email yourself the output of the script right at the end.

```
<?php
    ob_start();

    $time = time(); // Referenced in your email subjects. It will get confusing with lots of these emails otherwise. Gmail and other clients who use a conversation view will properly catalogue these emails if the subjects match.

    mail('your@email', 'Full Post Data - '.$time, print_r($_REQUEST, true));

    // STEP 1: Read POST data
    // reading posted data from directly from $_POST causes serialization 
    // issues with array data in POST
    // reading raw POST data from input stream instead. 

    [...] // Rest of your script here...

    $output_buffer = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    mail('your@email', 'Output buffer - '.$time, $output_buffer);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$cleanedFrom = 'Ashutosh';
            $to ='awesomeworks1@gmail.com; 
            $subject = 'CONTACT US';
            $headers = "From: " . $cleanedFrom . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
            $message= '<html><body>';
            $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #68A1D7;" cellpadding="15" width="450" align="center">';
            $message .= "<tr style='background: #68A1D7; color: #fff;'><td colspan='2'><strong>CONTACT US</strong></td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>" .$ram[0]['name'] . "</td></tr>";

            $message .= "<tr style='background:#68A1D7;'><td colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
            $message .= "</table>";
            $message .= "</body></html>";
            $send =    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
            if($send)
            {
            echo "<script> alert('Message Sent. Thank you') </script>";
            echo "<script>window.location='$webroot'</script>";
            exit;


            }
            else
            {
            echo "<script> alert('Message Not Sent. Thank you') </script>";
            echo "<script>window.location='$webroot'</script>";
            exit;

            }
```

Comment: *Please use this code for message this is working fine I have tesed*

Comment: please pass correct value in $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>" .$ram[0]['name'] . "</td></tr>";

Comment: Neither this answer nor your comment seem to make much sense in the context of this question.

Answer (score -1):

Turn on mail in your php.ini.

You need to have something like this:

In php.ini:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
;SMTP = localhost
;smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f  me@example.com
```

The lines that start with ";" are commented out. So make sure you uncomment the right part depending which operating system you are on.

Comment: I think i describe that i am working on a plugin and plugin installed many users and please tell me how can i edit THEIR php.ini file